# Concat Variable (date) and String in shell unix - bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to concat a var (date) and string to have a file with current date name.

My code.

```
days="$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")"
echo "SKIP" > ${days}_EMERGENCY.txt
```

but when I run, I get a file with a ? in file name, like this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT

Looking at symbol, ? stands for \r - could it be because I'm writing on notepad and then upload via ftp the .sh script?

EDIT 2

Tried with vi on local machine - now it's also worse.
[image]

Comment: I think it might be typographical quotes or charcters with zero display width slipped into. Please try as suggested in my comment below the answer proposal below.

Comment: Is it the GNU-bash and which Unix?

Comment: @sjsam yes GNU-bash on Linux

Comment: What's the result of `echo ${days}_EMERGENCY.txt`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your vi will have made the entire file DOS-style and so there will be another carriage return at the end of the echo statement

Try dos2unix or using an editor that allows you to change the line-ending style or

```
sed -i "s/$( printf '\015' )//g" yourscript
```

Comment: here it goes! that was problem!

Comment: Sometimes also adding semicolons to end statements is a fast fix for unsettled editing environments ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant, good suggestion, but "normally" shell programmers do without semicolons and there may be lines in the script that contain incomplete (continued) statements that will also make problems with stray CR, usually I think it even starts with `interpreter not found` as it tries using `/bin/bash^M` from the shebang...

Answer (score 4):

It works on my system (OS X) even with double quotes everywhere. For variation I used:

```
$> days="$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M')"
$> echo $days
20160601_1051
$> echo "SKIP" > ${days}_EMERGENCY.txt
$> ll ${days}_EMERGENCY.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  team  5 Jun  1 10:52 20160601_1051_EMERGENCY.txt
```

Comment: Please try as I did. I added the echo output and the file listing. Looks ok to me.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure that nothing is wrong, neither in my snippets, but output still this.

Comment: What is your echo $days output then? cf. also to the even simple answer from @alijandro. Maybe you copied typographical quote instead of ASCII quote character? Or have a unicode character with zero width inside? hexdump or xxd on the command should show. Like so: `echo 'echo "$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")"' | hexdump`

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the redundant double quote in your first variable assignment.

```
$ days=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)
$ echo $days #see what output will get?
$ echo "SKIP" > ${days}_EMERGENCY.txt
```