# Add date string to variable in sh script

Tags: shell, date, sh

I want to create a variable with the version of nextcloud_date like Nextcloud 18.0.2_20200403_1247.
`version=$(sudo -u www php /usr/local/www/nextcloud/occ --version)` returns Nextcloud 18.0.2 but I don't know how to append the _date_time.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563704/concat-variable-date-and-string-in-shell-unix-bash/37565172

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the post after solved that had the solution
${version}$(date +'_%F_%H%M')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat Variable (date) and String in shell unix - bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563704/concat-variable-date-and-string-in-shell-unix-bash)